# Custom view not resizing with auto-layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

Note: You don't have to check up the library to understand the question, I just brought it up for reference.

I implemented [DIDatePicker](https://github.com/noxt/DIDatepicker) in xcode. The way I inserted it in a `view` is: I inserted a `UIView` to the `viewController` with `auto-layout`, then at the Identity inspector I set the class to `DIDatepicker`.

[image]

The problem is, `DIDatepicker` doesn't resize to the view's size. I was thinking a possible solution may be, to set `DIDatePicker`  as the `view's class` in `viewDidLoad`, though I don't know how to do that.

My question is: if my theory is right, how can I set `DIDatePicker` as the `view's class`. If what I said is not true, how can I make `DIDatePicker` to resize with the `view`?

---

`DIDatePicker` has a `collectionView`; here is how it's defined:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init]; 
[collectionViewLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(kDIDatepickerItemWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))]; 
[collectionViewLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, kDIDatepickerSpaceBetweenItems, 0, kDIDatepickerSpaceBetweenItems)]; 
[collectionViewLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:kDIDatepickerSpaceBetweenItems];

_datesCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout:collectionViewLayout];
```

Comment: you need to add constraints to the view to size it to its parent view

Comment: Which view, the `DIDatePicker` (collectionView), or the view `DIDatePicket` is in?

Comment: The DIDatePicker view

Comment: Are you sure? Because `DIDatepicker` is the actual `view`, (it's the class of the `view`). Also, I can't access both together since they are initialized in different files.

Comment: Eric, I did not quite understand your problem.  But based on what I understand - you are correctly setting the class type in the IB you do not need to set the class again in `viewdidload`.  As far as the size goes - are you creating proper constraints?

Comment: Thanks your checking out my question!! I made constraints on the view in the storyboard. Then I made an nslog on the view's width, and it came out the correct size, but the collection view isn't.

Answer (score 0):

so I had the same exact problem as you.

The problem is that when you build DIDatepicker it builds its own collection view based on the view's **original** frame rather than the frame after auto-layout takes place.

The way to circumvent this problem is by not making the storyboard UIView of class DIDatepicker. Instead, just use a normal UIView and then create a DIDatepicker instance with the same frame as the UIView in the ViewDidLoad Method.

Here is an example. datePickerView is the UIView from the storyboard.

```
datepicker = DIDatepicker(frame: CGRectMake(datePickerView.frame.origin.x, datePickerView.frame.origin.y , self.view.frame.width, datePickerView.frame.height));
self.view.addSubview(datepicker!);
```

If that doesn't work try changing the frame and adding it to the datePickerView as a subview instead of the main view.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not totally sure if your "theory" about setting the main view to DIDatepicker is correct, but you should be able to test it by selecting the default "View" that is in the View Controller and setting a Custom Class on that. You shouldn't need to add a UIView first, just use the one that comes with the View Controller.

Comment: your answer doesn't address the issue at all.

Comment: I can't use that view, because I have other things in the view controller.